# WSDL Definition: what is "urn:arnleadservicewsdl"

Tags: web-services, symfony, wsdl, xml-namespaces

I try to create my first webservice on symfony. For that, I have applied this guide, and my Hello World is working: https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/soap_web_service.html

Now, I try to adapt given WSDL to my own code, but I'm not sure of what to do with this line in the WSDL definition:

```
xmlns:tns="urn:arnleadservicewsdl"
```

I guess it's important because it's used in my SoapAction:

```
 <soap:operation soapAction="urn:arnleadservicewsdl#hello" style="rpc"/>
```

What means this arnleadservicewsdl? Should I change it?
Thanks!